# docker can't expose the right port 9090 from docker using postman

Tags: python, docker, flask

my server.py has this code:

```
@app.route('/health', methods = ['POST'])
def check():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return jsonify({'response':'OK!'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=9090)
```

my dockerfile has EXPOSE at this:

```
FROM py_ubuntu_flask_numpy_torch_jysan_voice
RUN mkdir -p ./voice_flask/d
WORKDIR /voice_flask/d
COPY . /voice_flask/d
EXPOSE 9090
CMD ["python", "server.py"]
```

I build and run my image using this cmd:

```
docker build -t my_app .
docker run my_app
```

it launches and listens at :

```
 * Serving Flask app "server" (lazy loading)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:9090/
```

but in postman i can't even check health function:

```
"could not get response"
```

I suspect expose 9090 works on 0.0.0.0? not on 127.0.0.1?
How to fix it and test my app?

Comment: You also need to publish the port: `docker run -p 9090:9090 my_app`

Comment: @toydarian, i tried it, but it does not run

Comment: please run your container and do `docker ps` while it is running. add the output.

Comment: @toydarian, thx u bro, i just learned another thing - if old container still runs - it occupies the port!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXPOSE` does not expose any ports by itself.

If you ran your container like this:

```
docker run -P my_app
```

Docker would bind port 9090 inside your container to a random port on your host.

I suspect what you actually want is

```
docker run -p 9090:9090 my_app
```

which would bind port 9090 of your container to port 9090 on your host.

Furthermore your app is listening on 127.0.0.1, which means it rejects connections from outside the container.

What you need is

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True, port=9090, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: also i needed to kill other containers that occupied the port 9090!

Comment: Yes, only one process can be bound to any given port on your host.

Comment: another solution is to run docker with --rm option to stop it after done